# Dagger 2 component dependencies lifecycle

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Does Dagger 2 destroy the dependencies of a component when it's destroyed (the reference to the child component is set to null)?

I have 3 components in an Android app: an `AppComponent` (which has `Singleton` scope and lives as long as the app is running), an `ApiComponent`, and a `DataComponent`. `ApiComponent` and `DataComponent` both use some objects from `AppComponent` (e.g. the bus), and therefore I was thinking that I should add the `AppComponent` as a dependency to the other two components (`dependencies = {AppComponent.class}`). I don't need the `DataComponent` in my login activity, so I would like to ditch it (set the reference to null) on logout, but I wonder if the `AppComponent` too would get ditched/garbage-collected because it's defined as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an instance of AppComponent then garbage-collector cannot collect it.

Answer (score 2):

As I do and have seen most people doing you keep the instance of `AppComponent` within your `Application` and you initialize it `oncreate()`. This way it will live along with the application lifecycle and appear to be singleton.

And as long as you reuse this same component, you will get the same dependencies throughout your app.

All in all it just depends on where and how you store your objects. Be sure to place them appropriately for their respective lifecycle. If you have some component that uses some `Activity` in any way, be sure to not keep it longer than the activity exists.